# Sharepoint custom web part property does not show up in the toolbox

Tags: sharepoint, properties, web-parts

I have defined a boolean property as follows:

```
 [Browsable(true), Category("Display"), DefaultValue(false),
  WebPartStorage(Storage.Shared), FriendlyName("Obey Workflow"),
  Description("")]
  public bool ObeyWorkflow { get; set; }
```

I'm expecting it to render as a checkbox in the webpart's properties toolbox, however it doesn't show up. My web part is derived from the Sharepoint WebPart base class.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are on the right track. You just need to use different attributes.

```
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
[WebBrowsable(true)]
[Category("Display")]
[WebDisplayName("Obey Workflow")]  
[Description("")]  
public bool ObeyWorkflow { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you. I spent an entire day trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5):

@Jason, you're correct.  The syntax "Browsable", and "Category" are Sharepoint 2003 specific.  For SharePoint 2007, it's "WebBrowsable", and "SPWebCategoryName" respectively.

DefaultValue(false) is also SharePoint 2003 specific.

The equivalent in 2007, as far as I know, is to declare it initially beforehand, like this:

```
    private string _strMainFolder = "Reports"; //Here is the default value

    [WebBrowsable(true)]
    [WebDisplayName("SharePoint List Name")]
    [SPWebCategoryName("SharePoint List Name Settings")]
    [WebPartStorage(Storage.Shared)]
    [WebDescription("You would put the description here.")]
    [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
    public string strMainFolder
    {
        get { return _strMainFolder; }
        set { _strMainFolder = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

i think its `WebBrowsable(true)` instead of `Browsable(true)`

Comment: I have changed and it didn't help.